# How to overwrite reorder route?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I am trying to pass category id along with reorder route so I can list article based on the category. How can I overwrite reorder route like this

```
Route::get($segment.'/{id}/reorder', [
            'as'        => $routeName.'.reorder',
            'uses'      => $controller.'@reorder',
            'operation' => 'reorder',
        ]);

        Route::post($segment.'/{id}/reorder', [
            'as'        => $routeName.'.save.reorder',
            'uses'      => $controller.'@saveReorder',
            'operation' => 'reorder',
        ]);
```

Comment: `How to overwrite reorder route?` Changing path string by adding `$category` variable then adding `$category` parameter in appropriate controller's method followed by code change in that method?

Answer (score 0):

To order articles in each category you have to create a nested CRUD.

Here is a similar article to create one, which displays articles from a particular category:
https://backpackforlaravel.com/articles/tutorials/nested-resources-in-backpack-crud

1. Create nested CRUD.
2. Remove ReorderOperation from  ArticleCrudController.
3. Use ReorderOperation in nested `CategoryArticleCrudController`.

I hope this helps.